# Rails reading API response header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting familiarised with APIs. As a start, I am using the [Forecast API](https://developer.forecast.io/docs/v2).

In the docs, you will find a section entitled "Response Headers". What are they, and how can I use them?

Also, to get a response, it says you need to pass an API key, along with lat and long data. But aren't API keys supposed to be kept secret? Will anyone find out the contents of the request?

This is the code I have:

**Forecast model**

```
require 'json'
class Forecast
  include HTTParty
  debug_output $stdout
  default_params :apiKey => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  base_uri "api.forecast.io"
  format :json

  def self.get_weather(api,lat,long)
    @response = get("/forecast/#{apiKey}/#{lat},#{long}")
  end

  def self.show_weather
    JSON.parse(@response.body)
  end

end
```

**Forecast controller**

```
def index
    @weather = Forecast.get_weather("28.5355", "77.3910")
    @response = Forecast.show_weather
end
```

**Forecast view**

```
<%= @response["currently"]["summary"] %>
```

Comment: `default_params` will add the parameter to the URL - in this case, your url will end with `?apiKey=abcde`. In `self.get_weather`, `apiKey` will be undefined.

Answer (score 2):

You're asking a couple of different questions here.

- **Response headers**: They are part of an HTTP response, and contain information about the response. For example, they might tell you the MIME-type of the response - eg. `Content-Type: application/json`. In this case, Forecast use it to tell you how many API calls you've made (`X-Forecast-API-Calls`) and how long it took them to respond (`X-Response-Time`) as well as some caching information.
- **API keys**: Yes, these should be kept secret. The Forecast API works over HTTPS, so (in theory) your API key should be kept secret from people sniffing traffic on your network. The main danger is keeping it in your code and, for example, committing it to GitHub. You should figure out a safer way to store the API key. One example, whilst not perfect, would be to have it as an environment variable.

I hope that helps.

Comment: How can I access those header data. I did `JSON.parse(@response.headers)`, and it didnt work.

Comment: The response headers won't be JSON, but a Hash. So you can do something like: `@response.headers['X-Response-Time']`. To see the whole thing, try printing `@response.headers`, or `@response.headers.inspect`.

Comment: Thanks. One more thing about API key. Since i am setting the key in controller, how can I set it in model(and thereafter in env file) and include inside the get parameter(see updated ques, it has default_params). Simply calling `#{apiKey}` didnt work.